# What is format correct to create a new paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs

i have two examples:

```
\paragraph{title} hi a new text
```

or

```
\paragraph{Title}

hi a new text
```

What is the correct way?

is correct with space?

[image]

Comment: both produce the same output for me. Your first output is the expected behaviour (title and paragraph text on the same line), but I don't think there's anything 'incorrect' with using the second (personal taste).

Comment: Not that `paragraph` just shares the same name with the things you have in text called paragraph. You can write a whole book without ever using `\paragraph`. To start a new text paragraph, just leave a blank line in the input.

Answer (score 4):

The input you show does not produce the output that you show. As for all section headings, you get the same output whether or not you leave a blank line after the heading in the source.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{title} hi a new text

or

\paragraph{Title}

hi a new text

\end{document}
```

Note that despite its unfortunate name `\paragraph` is not for starting paragraphs, it is a 4th level section heading, to be used after `\subsubsection`.  It is easiest to see this if you tell LaTeX to number to a greater depth, if you add

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
```

To the above then the output is

[image]

with the 0.0.0  occurring as the example is missing `\section`, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`.

The style of section heading, run in or display (the two styles shown in your image) are document level settings that you can apply to all section, not just paragraph. By defauly the standard classes set level 4 headings run-in as shown but you can easily specify that they are set as display. Either using a package like `secsty` or simply copying the definition from `article` and changing one argument.

[image]

is produced by

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {5pt}% was {-1em} negative implies run-in, positive implies display
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\paragraph{title} hi a new text

or

\paragraph{Title}

hi a new text

\end{document}
```

All of the above is about 4th level subsubsubsections (started with `\paragraph`)
Paragraphs of text need no markup at all other than a blank line (`\par`) to separate them:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}

A paragraph of text doesn't use a \verb|\paragraph| command.
Very few documents have a 4 levels of sectioning and need \verb|\paragraph|.


This is a new paragraph just following the blank line
that ended the previous one.

\end{document}
```